# Limit of $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{3x^3y^2+xy^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I've run across a particular limit in my multivariable calculus class, that being:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{3x^3y^2+xy^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.
\end{equation}
I'm having quite a bit of trouble finding this limit using the squeeze theorem. Using polar coordinates (and assuming i'm not completely butchering everything), I believe we have that this particular limit evaluates to 0; however, using coordinate changes with limits feels a little uncomfortable and I would like to see if it can be done without it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that

$$\left\lvert\frac{3x^3y^2+xy^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right\rvert\leq\frac{3\lvert x\rvert(x^2+y^2)^2+\lvert x\rvert(x^2+y^2)^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}=4\lvert x\rvert\to0,$$

as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$, which I got from just using the triangle inequality and that

$$x^2\leq x^2+y^2,\quad y^2\leq x^2+y^2.$$

Answer (score 3):

We have

$$0\le \left|\frac{3x^3y^2+xy^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\right|\le \frac{3|x^3|y^2+|x|y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\le$$
$$\le \frac{3|x|x^2y^2+\frac32|x|y^4}{2x^2y^2+y^4}=\frac32|x|\to0$$